# Shuffle one of 2 identical lists, making sure no element in the shuffled list is in the same position as in the standard list

Tags: python, list, shuffle

Imagine

```py
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to shuffle `'b'`, making sure no element is in the same position as it's in `'a'`

Eg: after execution,
`[1,5,4,2,3]` is not okay because `'1'` is still in same position as it's in `'a'`

Comment: You need to shuffle `b` in non-conflicting manner OR you just need to check that `b` has no conflicts with `a` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I need to shuffle 'b' in a con-conflicting manner wrt 'a'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the code, but I can suggest a way to go:

- create a list of indexes to the positions in `b`. If the number of elements is odd, do not include the index to the last element
- shuffle the list you created
- iterate over the list, taking two indexes at a time and using those indexes to swap the elements in `b` they point to
- finally, if the number of elements is odd, swap the element you ignored before with a randomly chosen one